# How to automatically resume php-fpm?

Tags: debian, monitoring, timeout, php-fpm

I am using nginx+php-fpm on Debian Squeeze for a busy server and have had great difficulty to deal with maximum connections being reached. Here the problem is that php processes sometimes just die randomly under high load and leave the server with no php process. Then I need to manually restart php5-fpm service to bring back the server to life.

I am wondering how to avoid this to happen, or at least treat the symptoms by restarting the php5-fpm automatically whenever there is not php process left to listen to incoming requests. My relevant configs are:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 1400

pm.start_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 1s; #not sure it will be useful when pm=dynamic
pm.max_requests = 100000
request_terminate_timeout = 30
```

I appreciate your suggestions to cope with this nasty problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old watch dog script idea huh? Not the most elegant way to solve your problem but it can temporarily remedy the situation until you can figure out why its happening in the first place.

The actual problem needs to be addressed, It is either that the server needs to be more finely tuned, or that the server is not powerful enough to handle the load in the first place.

You have determined that the process actually dies. In which case it is as simple as determining if the process still exists. ps aux should do it for you.

for example:

```
ps aux|grep php-fpm|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
```

should output the process id of php-fpm. If it does not exist it needs to be restarted

so something along the lines of this should do the trick. (short and simple)

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps aux|grep php-fpm|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`
if [ $pid == '' ]
then
service php-fpm restart
fi
```

That script would be run as a crontab every minute. and it has NOT been debugged. so experiment with it and make sure it is working.

The problem with doing that with zombie processes is they actually exist and are "running" but not physically doing anything. in which case they would need to be killed first and then the process restarted.

Again the correct thing to do is to determine what is actually causing the service to crash. The watchdog script idea is only to buy you time.

Hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: Only the php processes dies, not the server. Not sure what you mean by 'becoming zumbies'. Could you please be more precise about writing the watchdog script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem of php-fcgi is: The process keeps alive after each request (unlike php-cgi). Each request increases the memory usage of the php process. At any time the process reaches the memory limit of php.

You could avoid this by decreasing

```
pm.max_requests = <value>
```

Answer (score 0):

> pm.max_children = 1400

You no not want to set the max children parameter that high. That's actually too high.

You might want to experiment with that, but, honestly:

Start with:

> pm.max_children = 50

And see how it goes.

Comment: Luis, max_children suitable value depends on the size of your traffic. Here I'm talking about a LARGE traffic.